# How to download files from webview in macOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, swift3

I am building a browser.

webview has list of function such as mainframeURL and accessibilityURL.

I also figure out how to get the update link by doing this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webview: WebView!

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView : WebView) {
    let url = self.webview.mainFrameURL

    if  url == nil {
        print("http://google.com/")   
    }
    else {
        print(url )
    }
}
```

I wonder how can I get access to download button of website from WebView.

Answer (score 0):

If user clicked a link, `webView(_:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)`
delegate method of WebView's `WebPolicyDelegate` will be invoked. You can process your download here.

Or if your "get access to download button" means getting a button element itself, you can dig `DOMElement` tree:

```
extension WebView {
    var rootElement: DOMElement {
        return self.mainFrame.domDocument.documentElement
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helped.  I need more tips to do my works. Webview of swift don't provide free functionality to download and upload file to any website.  It only can do browsing. However, I still want to get "download path" or "upload path" from the website via Webview by clicking the website down bottom or upload bottom. Therefore, I can download or upload file to the website.

Comment: It doesn't work. I wonder how can I improve it? how to use extension WebView {
    var rootElement: DOMElement {
        return self.mainFrame.domDocument.documentElement
    } Do you have any example? Thank you.
}

Answer (score 0):

I had try to implement this way.

```
func webView( _ webView: WebView!,
                      decidePolicyForNavigationAction actionInformation: [AnyHashable : Any]!,
                      request: URLRequest!,
                      frame: WebFrame!,
                      decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!){
   webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('Download').click()")
   llet url = request.url!.absoluteString 
    // I need to get the url link 
   print( url)
        }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  /// how can I implement the function to make it work ?
    self.webView(NSwebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction: nil, request: nil, frame: nil, decisionListener: nil)
}
```

Comment: In order to get url link in webview by clicking it, webView( _ webView: WebView!, decidePolicyForNavigationAction actionInformation: [AnyHashable : Any]!, request: URLRequest!,frame: WebFrame! decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!) must be used. But I can't get it run in viewDidLoad() to activate the function. Please let me know how to do it. Thank you.